# Placing a function in dictionary

Tags: python

In Perl, if I want the value of a hash element to be a reference to an anonymous subroutine:

```
my $hash = { hi => sub { print "dummy" } };
$hash->{hi}->();   # Prints "dummy".
```

Is there an equivalent way for the previous hash/dict in Python?

Note: I need the key value to contain the function, not a reference to redirect to the function

Comment: You say that you need the key to contain the function. However, in your perl example, isn't the value the function instead of the key?

Comment: yes, sorry it is the value of the key

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you can use a lambda function to make an anonymous function:

```
d = {'key': lambda x: print(x)}
d['key']("hello")
# prints "hello"
```

If you need a more complex function, you are better off writing the function and adding a reference to the dictionary.

[per comment] The parameter isn't required for lambdas. You can also use:

```
d = {'key': lambda: print("Hello")}
```

and call it without the argument:

```
d['key']() # also prints "hello"
```

Comment: can't I create a function that don't require any variables? Like calling it without giving it any value

Comment: The parameter isn't required for lambdas @MobrineHayde. You can also use: `lambda: print("Hello")` and call it without the argument: `d['key']()`